# how to join (specific) array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, join

this is my arrar:

```
var arr = [{
    learn : {text: ["ab", "cd"]}
}];
```

and I want to join it an result must be something like that: `"[ab][cd]"`
I mean it must be string.

I tried to join with this code:

```
var joined = arr[0].learn.text.join("][")
```

but result is this: `"ab][cd"` (string)

[this is demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3wjxedre/)

Comment: If you already have `ab][cd` and it's just missing `[` from the start and `]` from the end, can you really not think of any way to get them there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be as simple as

```
var joined = "[" + arr[0].learn.text.join("][") + "]";
```

just prepend `"["` and append `"]"`

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use Array.map and a '[fat] arrow function' with Array.join:

```
["ab", "cd"].map(v => '['+v+']').join('');
```

Array.map executes a function for each element of an array.
In this case that function is a 'arrow function' which returns the element wrapped in square brackets as a string.
Then Array.join joins the strings together.

Arrow functions are a shorthand way to define an anonymous function.

> **Basic Syntax**
>
> (param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements } (param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
>   // equivalent to:  => { return expression; }
>
> // Parentheses are optional when there's only one parameter:
>   (singleParam) => { statements }
>    singleParam  => { statements }
>
> // A function with no parameters requires parentheses: () => {statements }

More on 'arrow functions' here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way would be

```
var joined = arr[0].learn.text.map(function(s){ return "["+s+"]" }).join();
//Gives => "[ab],[cd]"
```